# Add loading screen to iphone application

Tags: iphone

i am new in iphone app development. I am using window based application. I want to add loading screen (screen with red arrow) shown in following figure to my application above my main view to show that application in trying to connect to the server. 
Here is the link for image ( sorry i am new user)
http://img10.imageshack.us/i/16467623.jpg
How can i add this screen? that screen contains activity indicator & text only. After connection is established i want to hide that window. plz help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Create a small UIView (can be done with IB or programmatically) place there UISpinner and UIProgressBar. And when it is necessary just add on the superview your small UIView with these outlets.